# JavaScript - Replacing array value within object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, pass-by-reference, overwrite

I'm trying to write a function that normalizes features (between 0 and 1) in a dataset. I want to iterate through all the features and *replace* values as I normalize them. Normalization works well, but I'm unable to overwrite the previous value.

```
Data.prototype.normalize = function(dataset) {

    // Get the extent for each feature
    for (var feature = 0; feature < this.featureCount; feature++) {
        var extent = this.getExtent(feature, dataset),
            min    = extent[0],
            max    = extent[1];

        // uses extent to normalize feature for all companies
        for (var company = 0; company < this.companies.length; company++) {
            var value      = this.companies[company][dataset][feature],
                normalized = this.normalizeValue(value, min, max);

            value = normalized;
        }
    }

}
```

It all fails at

```
value = normalized;
```

If I console.log(value) after overwriting it everything seems to work, but only within the scope of the function. Outside of this scope the original value remains.

```
data.companies[n] = { features : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], other properties... }
```

Here is an example of the feature array within my main object.

Any thoughts on how to fix this?

Thank you!

Comment: [Primitive types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Primitive) are never passed by reference in Javascript.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order for the change to be reflected in your object as opposed to the function, you need to explicitly set the property of your object.

Modify your `for` loop to explicitly set the normalized value like so:

```
for (var company = 0; company < this.companies.length; company++) {
    var value      = this.companies[company][dataset][feature],
        normalized = this.normalizeValue(value, min, max);

    this.companies[company][dataset][feature] = normalized; // explicitly set value
}
```

Comment: Nice psychic debugging.